# How to pass values to LWC from js-meta.xml file

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am new to LWC, I tried to create a very simple component which is supposed to show a value from App Builder configuration and show slds icon.

However, the error message `Error during LWC component connect phase: [headerName is not defined]` is showing up. how to fix this?
[image]

- header.html

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title={headerTitle} icon-name={iconName}>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

- header.js

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Header extends LightningElement {
    @api headerName;
    @api headerIconType;
    @api headerIconName;
    headerTitle = '';
    iconName = '';

    connectedCallback() {
        this.headerTitle = headerName;
        this.iconName = headerIconType + ':' + headerIconName;        
    }
}
```

- header.js-meta.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage,lightning__AppPage,lightning__HomePage">
            <property label="headerName" name="headerName" type="String" required="true"/>
            <property label="headerIconType" name="headerIconType" type="String" required="true" datasource="Utility, Doctype, Standard, Custom, Action"/>
            <property label="headerIconName" name="headerIconName" type="String" required="true"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the answer, but in your connectedCallback you still need to use the `this` keyword.

```
connectedCallback() {
    this.headerTitle = this.headerName;
    this.iconName = this.headerIconType + ':' + this.headerIconName;        
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nick Cook, my bad, just like a typo. thanks for pointing out.